# in vim: "mark" current window, so I can jump to it

Tags: vim

I have several windows open at a time. Some of them with the same buffer.

Is there a way I can "mark" the current window, so I can jump to it later?
And if the marked window has been closed, how can I detect that?

By 'Window', I mean I have done :split several times.

Answer (score 2):

**If you have so many concurrent windows that you lose track, I'd change the workflow.** Do you really need that many buffers *visible* at the same time?

Vim supports marking files (via the uppercase marks), but not windows. How about including the window number in the *statusline*:

```
:set statusline+=\ %{winnr()}
```

Then, you can mentally take note of the number and use a command like `[N]<C-W><C-W>` to jump back to window number `[N]`.

Comment: +1 Uppercase marks are super handy. I use `mM` as my most common uppercase mark because it is so easy to type

Comment: I definitely have the window number in my statusline so I can quickly jump to arbitrary windows. Even better: highlight it with one of the user-highlight groups, for example `%*1%{winnr()}%*` instead of the undecorated version. This way it is easy to scan for!

Comment: The "I'd change workflow" is not really pertinent... It could be used for plugin or macro that work across windows...

Comment: @hl037_ The question does not mention scripting, and the use of the active "so that I can jump" suggests interactive use. For scripting, there are several possibilities (like setting a window-local variable and locating it later, or the Vim 8 `win_getid()` mentioned in the second answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Vim8 this is very simple. See `:win_getid()` and `:win_gotoid()`